# Correct form of /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, hosts

I've always thought that the correct format of /etc/hosts was 

`1.1.1.1 fully.qualified.name shortname alias`

We're upgrading our core software and some of the vendors utilities are failing as they require the short name to be switched with the FQDN.

This breaks `dnsdomainname` (returns nothing) and also `hostname -f` (returns the short name).

We've gone back to the vendor who want a detailed response on why they should change their utilities.

I'm looking for reasons why they are wrong.  All I have so far is that it breaks standard utilities but I need more than this.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The man page looks fairly specific. You can try beating them over the head with that. But in practice the order really should not matter (though Debian based systems kind of care about it, but that's just one of many of Debian's long standing design flaws and absurdities..).

Comment: Try to switch the precedence of hosts line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Thanks all.  I've pointed them at the man page and commented on dnsdomainname and hostname -f.  Just have to wait and see what happens.